# Have Automator parse down folders and list all filenames without their extension

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, file-extensions

Automator newbee question here. I've searched around and just can't find what I need (nor fully grasp how things work :-( ).

I would like to have Automator parse thru a given folder, which is subdivided in dozens of folders. Each of these sub-folders contain a varying number of files with their respective file extension (.mov, .mp4, .wmv and others). Ultimately, the automated process would output the list of all files, minus their file extension name into a text file. There should be anywhere between 50 to 200 names in total.

Sample Sources:
RootFolder > SubFolder1 > File1.mov, File2.mp4
RootFolder > Subfolder2 > File3.wmv, File4.mov, File5.mp4

Output text file content:
File1
File2
File3
(...)
This text file could be located at the RootFolder's level or on the Desktop.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Alain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Automator and Scripting Approach

The Automator Actions you want are:

- Ask for Finder Items, with **Type** set to **Folders**.
- Run Shell Script, with **Shell** set to **/usr/bin/perl**.
- New Text File

For the shell script, copy and paste in:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use File::Find;

find(sub {
    return if (-d $File::Find::name);
    my($filename,undef,undef) = fileparse($_,qr/\.[^.]*/);
    print $filename."\n";
}, shift);
```

[image: Automator list files]

You can use the **New TextEdit Document** action if you want the resulting file list to appear in TextEdit but not saved to disk.

[image]

To learn more about using Automator, see Apple's [Mac Basics: Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488).

Comment: Thank you very much Graham - very generous of you. Unfortunately, the script approach is not working for me. Should an output file name be defined somewhere? Just to confirm as well: the script approach is an alternative altogether, not a script to be run by Automator, correct?

Comment: Yes, the script is an alternative. The output will be printed but can be redirected to a file once it is proven to work. Please can you append what error you are seeing and what you have tried.

Comment: Sure thing. I've brought everything to the Desktop. If I use the "full path" approach as you described, I do not get any error nor output on screen. In the terminal, I type:  
perl /Users/aduroche/Desktop/ /Users/aduroche/Desktop/TheFolder/  
Now, by using the following syntax (running the command from the Desktop level) I did get one error output:  
Desktop aduroche$ ./ListFolderContentInTextFile.txt TheFolder/
./ListFolderContentInTextFile.txt: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `sub'
', shift);$filename."\n";def) = fileparse($_,qr/\.[^.]*/);v perl
  
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I have updated the answer to combine an Automator and shell scripting approach. You can now extend the workflow to avoid selecting a folder each time or pass the output more actions for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a Run Shell Script action:

[image]

Or just run a command like this in Terminal:

```
find ~/path/to/dir -type f|sed 's|.*/||;s|\.[^.]*$||'>~/Desktop/files.txt
```

Comment: Also good - thank you. One caveat: as you repeat the process, the new list is concatenated (added) to the older one.